# Webhooks in Salesforce professional

Tags: professional-edition, webhooks

I need to setup a webhook on Salesforce Professional Edition.
For example, if someone creates an account, I want the request to be sent to an external server.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, the Professional Edition (e.g. Lightning Professional) does not have workflow or automation, so you can't generally set up code to call external systems. I do believe that at one point workflow and automation was available as a paid upgrade for Professional Edition, but I do not see that as an option in the current [product comparison chart](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf). You might want to contact your account executive to confirm what your options are.

Comment: Do you have a link to that chart?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've linked the current PDF in to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Professional Edition has Process Builder as the only automation tool .The reference for this is [below](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/new-editions-2016.html)

You can spin a sample professional edition to see what you can achieve by [simple signup](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-pe.jsp)

Also on the possibility of what you need is definitely doable .You will need to create a own managed package solution and pass the security review and list on an appexchange as ISV partner .

Check the below [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm).Also to push free apps on appexchange it does not cost you anything .Also security review charge is free for free applications .